# TimescaleDB querying occurrence within time interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I am learning TimescaleDB to query occurrences within a specified time interval. I came across the `time_bucket` function, however, I would need to account for the overlapping intervals as well.

Let us consider I have 5 events at times:

```
12:23 12:24 12:25 12:26 12:27
```

`time_bucket` of TimescaleDB returns the data only in the buckets `12:20 - 12:25` and `12:25 - 12:30`.

**My requirement is that I need to find exactly 5 occurrences within 5 mins .**

So this time can be also in the range `12:23 - 12:27`. But `time_bucket` function returns only the no of values in bucket as `12:30` - 2 and `12:35` - 3. Kindly help me on if this can be done in Timescaledb.

Comment: Have you looked to [Window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-window.html) in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @k_rus If can you please provide any example related to the above requirement, It will be very helpful.

Comment: Interesting question, I do think that a window function could work, should be something like `SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY foo ORDER BY ts RANGE BETWEEN '2 min 30s' PRECEDING AND '2 min 30s' FOLLOWING` see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS

However, this is an interesting question that might also be well supported by some different syntax if you want to check out our new Timescale Analytics project and start an issue or a discussion that could be nice! https://github.com/timescale/timescale-analytics/discussions